# Membase - getting a list of all keys using TAP

Tags: membase

I'm trying to figure out how to modify [tap_example.py](https://github.com/membase/ep-engine/blob/master/management/tap_example.py) to get me a list of all keys in my Membase instance, but I'm having trouble getting started.

I think I need to set TAP_FLAG_DUMP somewhere, but I'm not sure where, and can't find any relevant documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do two things:

1. Use port 11210 to use TAP, per a comment from Perry Krug [here](http://www.couchbase.org/forums/node/497).
2. Modify tap.py correctly, and memcachedConstants.py too - per [here](http://groups.google.com/group/membase/browse_thread/thread/20db4fb1e25b42e0/8e728adefe93e6e2?lnk=gst&q=tap+all+keys#8e728adefe93e6e2).